# New Column in Doctrine / CodeIgniter app produces Column not found: 1054 Unknown column error

Tags: codeigniter, doctrine

`Doctrine_Connection_Mysql_Exception [ 42 ]: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'allocation_rule_number' in 'field list'`

I have the above error after adding a new column to my table manually via mysql command prompt. I have traced it down to synchronizeWithArray in my controller - for some reason in my code igniter controller

`$this->_table->columns`

is missing the new column I added so synchronizeWithArray is failing. I know that it's in the POST data so I'm not sure what part of Doctrine has the old table definition.

`if ($is_update)
        {
          $this->license->synchronizeWithArray($this->tmp_record);
        }`

Any ideas why would this happen or how to diagnose?

Answer (score 1):

I forgot to add the same column to the license_versions table. I figured it out by checking the MySQL query log, which was invaluable in pointing out that exactly how it was trying to modify the wrong table!